# Add a .asmx file to asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to add a .asmx file to an MVC project and have .asmx code call the controller and have the controller return data to the .asmx code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you need functionality specific to the controller (such as rendered output, web context, etc), you could take out the logic you want to execute in the controller and put it in a new class and have both controller and webservice call the method in the new class.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to add a .asmx file to
>   an MVC project

Yes.

> asmx code call the controller and have
>   the controller return data to the
>   .asmx code?

Yes.

```
var controller = new YourController();
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(this.Context);
var routeData = new RouteData();
var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData);
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, controller);

var result = controller.YourAction();
```

But I discourage to do that. Instead **move common logic into a separate service** layer and use that one.

Answer (score 4):

You can call your asmx by adding an Ignore Route path in your global.asax RegisterRoute method

Comment: how do you do this? ignore route path sounds promising

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the first part (though I assume it's possible), but the second part is simple.

It can of course access the controller because the controller is just a class with functions that return results. It will simply be a matter of setting the controller's HttpContext correctly, and then invoking the action method that you want. You can then do whatever you want with the ActionResult - render it to a string for instance.